# Customizing jupyterlab GUI to have a basic GUI

Tags: jupyter-lab

I'm trying to customize the jupyterlab GUI, so that the user just opens the notebook and runs it.

The file browner should stay, allowing the user to have access to multiple notebooks.

I'm having problems with disabling the 'New Folder', ' Upload Files' from the FileBrowser-toolbar. The Launcher is disabled but the icon is still there.

I've done everything else by using `jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/...` and with a `overrides.json` file.

I'm working with `jupyterlab 3.6.3`

Thanks for your help

---

**File Browser options**

[image]

----------------------------------------